# Django "Deadlock found" with transaction.atomic

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, atomic

I have a function that updates a model or creates a new entry if it doesnt already exists:

```
try:            
  obj=model.objects.get(id=id)
  setattr(obj, 'completed', True)
  obj.save()
except:
  model.objects.create(id=x, user=y, completed=True)
```

In a specific case this function is called twice so fast that it was creating two entries on the database, because of that, I included a unique constraint to make sure it wont ever happen.

But then I started getting this error:

```
Duplicate entry '1-13' for key 'x_y_z_uniq'
```

So I tried using lock like:

```
with transaction.atomic():
  try:            
    obj=model.objects.select_for_update().get(id=id)
    setattr(obj, 'completed', True)
    obj.save()
  except:
    model.objects.create(id=x, user=y, completed=True)
```

But now is raising this error:

```
(Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction)
```

I wanted a way that the first call of the function would create a new entry and the second one would update that entry, but the second call simply fails due to the deadlock, how can I make it so the second call will wait for the first one to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me u can use here simple `.update()` method:
`obj=model.objects.filter(id=id).update(completed=True)`
Even more, you can refactor all your code to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
obj, created = model.objects.update_or_create(
    id=id,
    defaults={'id': x, 'user': y, 'completed': True}
)
```

Comment: update_or_create is using transaction atomic nd select for update so it will behave the same as the one in the qst